# How to make multi filter on django orm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-filters

I have a table with fields:

```
No. | name  | utc_date | utc_time  |
------------------------------------
1   | John  | 181014   | 140104.12 |
2   | Mark  | 181014   | 152312.01 |
3   | Kim   | 181015   | 092345.23 |
4   | Jane  | 181015   | 234543.32 |
```

How can I create Django ORM query like that: ?

```
(utc_date >= 181014, utc_time >=150000.00) AND (utc_date <= 181015, utc_time <= 150000.00 )
```

***I tried to make as shown below, but it doesn't work**:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(utc_date__gte=181014, 
                       utc_date__lte=181015, 
                       utc_time__gte=150000.00, 
                       utc_time__lte=150000.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple filters, use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q).

In your case it should look like

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyTable.objects.filter(Q(utc_date__gte=181014) & 
                       Q(utc_date__lte=181015) & 
                       Q(utc_time__gte=150000.00) &
                       Q(utc_time__lte=150000.00))
```

Comment: I tried to make a query with that method also. But the filter makes only under `utc_time`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have separation datetime to datefield and timefield which name is utc_date and utc_time, you wish is to filter data in datetime range,do like:

```
# first get data in date range:
data = MyTable.objects.filter(utc_date__gte=181014, utc_date__lte=181015)
# second exclude other
data1 = data.exclude(utc_date=181014, utc_time__lt=150000.00)
data2 = data1.exclude(utc_date=181015, utc_time__gt=150000.00)
```

data2 is what you need.

The main idea is if i want get data in `2018-10-14 15:00` ~  `2018-10-15 15:00`,I get all data in `2018-10-14 00:00` ~ `2018-10-15 24:00`,then delete data in `2018-10-14 00:00` ~  `2018-10-14 15:00` and `2018-10-15 15:00` ~  `2018-10-15 24:00`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work because adding multiple criteria inside a `.filter()` just ANDs them all together.

I think the simplest and most readable way to solve this is to look at each date individually.  We'll use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to enable logical ORs:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyTable.objects.filter(Q(utc_date=181014, utc_time__gte=150000.00) | 
                       Q(utc_date=181015, utc_time__lte=150000.00))
```